# Zebra-striping nested lists with CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-class

It's easy to style lists and rows with alternating backgrounds using the the `:nth-child(odd/even)` pseudo-classes, but if you try to apply it to nested lists, it starts to look hideous.

My question is, is there any way to alternate by depth / hierarchy, where, for example, a parent color alternates with the child elements' indefinitely. Eg:

- red

  - blue
  - blue

    - red
    - red

      - blue
    - red
  - blue

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3TuN/212/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer, no. Long answer, yes, by targeting the nested items, eg:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {background:blue}
li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even) {background:blue}
li:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(odd) {background:blue}
```

But beyond 2 or three levels you're probably going to need a lot of rules.

You could do it with javascript as well, by walking down the tree and incrementing a counter, applying the style when the counter is odd or even.

Comment: oh ya, js would be way easier.  if (color == "green") { color = red; } else { color = green; }  Done.